# Root for Huawei P9

Tags: root-access, huawei

I am looking for a root for Huawei p9. I`ve tried some like kingo, poot and frama, but none worked. The error message was: No exploits found on device. Does this mean my device is not rootable?

Answer (score 1):

Stop relying on one-click root wares, most recent phones are patched against them.

Usually you need to have a custom recovery (e.g. TWRP) in place. Read through [XDA-Developers: Huawei P9](http://forum.xda-developers.com/p9) to get an understanding. [One post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/p9/how-to/guide-root-huawei-p9-t3367800) walks you through rooting, though without knowing what device variant and firmware version you're on, it's unclear whether it will work for you.

As always, back things up and root at your own risk.